# Sails doesnt populate on large queries

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, sails.js, waterline

I have a legacy mysql database I'm working with consisting of 5 tables, 2 of which are join/junction tables. I have a method in a controller that queries one of the tables and populates some fields via the join tables. This works fine for queries less than 1632 items but for anything above the populate field arrays don't contain any data. No errors are thrown, the fields are just blank e.g. `"user": []`. Logging the SQL queries into the MySQL container shows that for items > 1632 the 2nd query which handles the population (inner_joins etc) doesnt come in.

Has anyone else experienced this before? I have tested this on sails 0.12.0 & 0.11.4 and sails-mysql 0.11.4 & 0.11.1 which is sitting on top of node v4.2.6. I am running the api and database in docker containers and have tested provisioning more RAM to the docker host to no avail.

Comment: Just to be clear, Waterline joins in RAM _only when it is performing populates between different databases_.  Otherwise, it uses an optimized approach at the adapter level, generating native queries using joins or falling back to UNION queries when joins are impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My particular issue was down to the MySQL `thread_stack` size being to small.

My path for debugging was to view the waterline query coming into node mysql module by adding a `console.log` to the `Connection.prototype.query` function in the node mysql module within sails-mysql. I then took the query waterline was making and ran it directly in the database which produced an error `ERROR 1436 (HY000): Thread stack overrun:  246168 bytes used of a 262144 byte stack, and 16000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.`

Many thanks to the guys at SailsJS for helping me figure it out. The particular discussion can be found at https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3561